# Why jQuery can't execute a loaded script if I load (before it) jQuery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've an application that check if there is jQuery on the current loaded script.
If not, I retrieve it with `getScript` and I load a function, which basically retrieve html/js serialized in json by `$.getJSON`, and than execute it:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    if (typeof $ == 'function') {
        thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary = true;
    }

    function getScript(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            };
        };

        head.appendChild(script);
    };

    getScript(AbsURL + '/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', function () {
        if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
            if (!thisPageUsingOtherJSLibrary) {
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    MyFunction($);
                });
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}

function MyFunction($) {
    $.getJSON(AbsURL + "/widget/Init.aspx?" + queryString + "&callback=?", function (html) {
        JsonToHtml(html);
    });

    function JsonToHtml(html) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(html, function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        });

        $('body').prepend(items.join(''));
    }
}
```

the fact is: if I have jQuery when I load the main page, the loaded (deserialized) script is executed, else it add on the body, but nothing is executed.

Which step am I missing here?

The problem is the execution of the loaded script. 
This is executed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.log("ciaopollo");</script>
```

This not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function (w, d) { var loader = function () { var s = d.createElement("script"), tag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.src = "http://cdn.iubenda.com/iubenda.js"; tag.parentNode.insertBefore(s, tag); }; if (w.addEventListener) { w.addEventListener("load", loader, false); } else if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent("onload", loader); } else { w.onload = loader; } })(window, document);</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deferred.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) from [$get.JSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Since `$get.JSON()` is async and implements the Promise interface, so you get deferred properties such as `.done()`, `.error()` etc.

So ensure that you response is successful then do the next thing, otherwise handle the error.

Example from JQuery documentation:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

Alternatively, load a script by embedding it in head if you need to acquire  it before [critical render path](https://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/), some developers use this strategy to prevent javascript from blocking the page from loading. The following example is an excerpt from code to acquire webfonts:

```
// this is just another way to create '<script src...'> and
// a method used by placing it in <head></head> so its processed
// before critical render path.
(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " wf-loading";
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

Hope this helps.

**Response to comments below here for formatting reasons:**
try the following:

```
// optional reference to d, declare var _d;
$.getJSON( file, query , function( d ) { 
  // do nothing or _d = d;
}) 
.done(function( d ) { 
  // call fn(d) 
});
```

Comment: Uhm, I've added the function `JsonToHtml(html)` inside `.done`, but nothing change. It can't render the loaded script :(

Comment: I mean, once I load the script, jQuery (loaded dynamically) is already loaded. I don't understand why it can't "execute" the script deserialized inside `JsonToHtml` (here is the problem).

Comment: @markzzz answered by 'UPDATE' above, wasnt able to format answer in this input.

Comment: What's the purpose of the function above? It's the same... what should I check? I don't follow you here :(

Comment: The problem is the exe. This work: `<script>console.log("ciaopollo");</script>` it is executed without problem. This is not executed: `<script type="text/javascript">(function (w, d) { var loader = function () { var s = d.createElement("script"), tag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.src = "http://cdn.iubenda.com/iubenda.js"; tag.parentNode.insertBefore(s, tag); }; if (w.addEventListener) { w.addEventListener("load", loader, false); } else if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent("onload", loader); } else { w.onload = loader; } })(window, document);</script>`

Comment: Read the comment above (or the updated question). May be the problem is on the script itself that I'm running...mmm...

Comment: :) yes, ensure that jquery or other decencies you require exists before aything else use the callback() then safely call $getJSON()... do stuffs that may need the dependencies. apologies for the back and forth, this 'ENTER' key and unformatted text input is a pain.

Comment: Added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056796/same-script-is-loaded-not-loaded-due-to-when-jquery-is-loaded-why where you can easily check what's happening. Can you remove this answer? So I can delete the question.

Comment: does that means you want me to delete my answers? or paste there? im lost

Comment: Delete this :) So I can remove this pseudo-dublicate topic :)