# A script is executed/not executed due to when jQuery is loaded - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a problem I have. Try this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/t8gk9fwg/7/):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    function getScript(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
            };
        };

        head.appendChild(script);
    };

    getScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js', function () {
        if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                MyFunction($);
            });
        }
    });   
} else {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        MyFunction($);
    });
}

function MyFunction($) {
    $.getJSON("http://archiesocial.progettiarchimede.it/widget_privacy/test.aspx?asd=1&callback=?", function (d) {
    }).done(function(d) { 
        JsonToHtml(d);
    });
}    

function JsonToHtml(html) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(html, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('body').prepend(items.join(''));
}
```

you will notice that my code check if jQuery is loaded. If not, it loads a version from external source; than retrieve a JSON, parse it and "execute it".

As you can see, the script loaded inside the body it is not loaded at all (*this is my problem*).

Now, try to choose a version/library of jQuery in the fiddle (1.8.3 is ok) and press play: you will see the script/button render as well: the script is executed!!!

Why loading jQuery first (here) render the script, and load jQuery later won't execute the script? Can you help me?

Comment: Any error(s) in browser console?

Comment: @LShetty No error in jsFiddle which replicates issue

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from the final script you're loading (http://cdn.iubenda.com/iubenda.js). However, that code is minified, so the problem won't be easy to diagnose.

Comment: It sounds like the minified script is using window onload event for setting iframe, which is then not fired because the window is already loaded. EDIT: ya it is using `w.addEventListener(\"load\", loader, false);` or depending browser`w.attachEvent(\"onload\", loader);` But at time this script is called, the window is already loaded

Comment: Ok. But why jQuery loaded before should made the difference? It's because, loading external resource, end the "load" event? How can I fix it? @Archer solution seems to works, but not so ideal...

Comment: @markzzz Appending script as you do to load jQuery is async, and so it isn't take into account regarding window onload event. This is how i understand the issue. See difference here http://jsfiddle.net/t8gk9fwg/18/ and here http://jsfiddle.net/t8gk9fwg/20/

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to force onload event to be refired if it is already fired because as you are loading jQuery (if undefined), this event is already fired. This is a workaround:

```
function JsonToHtml(html) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(html, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('body').prepend(items.join(''));
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') { // check if document is complete
        var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
        evt.initEvent('load', false, false);
        window.dispatchEvent(evt); // then redispatch onload event
    }
}
```

### -DEMO-

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the scope. The functions MyFunction() and JsonToHtml() are out of the scope. (Remember you are working with async functions like getJSON) Maybe my explanation are wrong, but the code works. :P

With this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/t8gk9fwg/19/) you have no problem.

```
function _test(){}
_test.prototype = {
    hasjQuery: function(){
        if(typeof window.jQuery !='undefined' && !_test.prototype.otherLibrary() ) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    },
    otherLibrary: function(){
        if (typeof document.$ == 'function') {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    },
    inyectjQuery: function(url, success){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.id = "delete";
        done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
    },
    myFunction: function(){
        urljQuery = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
        if(_test.prototype.hasjQuery()){
            jQuery.getJSON("http://archiesocial.progettiarchimede.it/widget_privacy/test.aspx?asd=1&callback=?", 
                function (d) {
                    _test.prototype.JsonToHtml(d);
                }).done(function() { 
                    console.log("Success getJSON action");
                });
        }else{
            _test.prototype.inyectjQuery(urljQuery, function(){
                if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') {
                    console.log("unable to load jQuery");
                }else{
                    jQuery.getJSON("http://archiesocial.progettiarchimede.it/widget_privacy/test.aspx?asd=1&callback=?", 
                    function (d) {
                        _test.prototype.JsonToHtml(d);
                    }).done(function() { 
                        console.log("Success getJSON action");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },
    JsonToHtml: function(html){
        var items = [];
        jQuery.each(html, function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        });

        jQuery('body').prepend(items.join(''));
    }
}
test = new _test();
test.myFunction();
```

Comment: If someone think my answer is wrong, i like to know why. So please, give me some feedback.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but they're not out of scope.  They have global scope in the code above, so they can't be.

Comment: Being strict you are right. But when you can't reach the function/vars, these are not out of the scope?

Comment: Since they have global scope, the only way they would never be defined is if the script falls over before it gets to them and ceases to execute.  If that happens then the scope of those functions is irrelevant.